# QT signal-slot issue. Signal is emitted, slot isn't called. No warnings, no errors, no messages

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create GUI for hardware control through Modbus RTU, but when I try to implement all connected to Serial Port and messages in separate thread I catch problems. I use Qt 5.9.
Here is my code's extracts:

some.cpp:

```
some::some(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::some)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    modbusH = new modbusHandler(values);
    modbusThread = new QThread();
    connect(modbusThread, &QThread::started, modbusH, &modbusHandler::process);
    connect(modbusH, &modbusHandler::portOpenSuccess, this, on_port_opened);
    connect(modbusH, &modbusHandler::portCloseSuccess, this, on_port_closed);
    connect(this, &some::port_open_request, modbusH, &modbusHandler::openPort);
    connect(this, &some::port_close_request, modbusH, &modbusHandler::closePort);
    modbusH->moveToThread(modbusThread);
    modbusThread->start();
}


void some::on_openClosePortButton_clicked()
{
      emit port_open_request(ui->portsComboBox->currentText(), localBaudRate.at(ui->baudRateComboBox->currentIndex()));
}
```

some.h:

```
class some : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:

    void port_open_request (QString, int);


private:

    modbusHandler* modbusH;
    QThread* modbusThread;
};

#endif // some_H
```

modbusHandler.cpp

```
void modbusHandler::openPort(QString portName, int baudRate)
{
    device->setConnectionParameter(QModbusDevice::SerialPortNameParameter, portName);
    device->setConnectionParameter(QModbusDevice::SerialBaudRateParameter, (QSerialPort::BaudRate)baudRate);
    device->connectDevice();
    emit portOpenSuccess(device->state() == QModbusDevice::ConnectedState);
}
```

modbusHandler.h:

```
class modbusHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:

    void sessionFinished();

    void portCloseSuccess(bool ok);

    void portOpenSuccess(bool ok);

public slots:

    void process();

    void startSession();

    void openPort(QString portName, int baudRate);

    void closePort();

};

#endif // MODBUSMASTER_H
```

The first problem is: signal *port_open_request* from *some* is successfully connected with *openPort* slot from *modbusHandler*, emitted but *openPort* slot isn't executed.

I looked for answer but with no result. *QString* and *int* are registered type.

Excuse me if there are some obvious errors: they may be done when i created crop version of code for this question. I really tried to catch errors in my code during several days without any success.

**!!! P.S.** I've forgot to mention, that there are some signal-slot connections between these objects, that work! For example, if serial port is opened, signal about it is emitted and slot of my *some* object is called.

Comment: Can you crop even more of your code? I see a lot of code which is not need to analyzing the problem.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint on the `emit` line to make sure that's even getting called?

Comment: Of course. I've even detected it with QSignalSpy with checking correct arguments' passing.

Comment: where is `on_port_opened` ? I can't see it in `class Some`.

Comment: It's defined in full version of code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but the canonical way would be to first move the modbusH object to the modbusThread and then do the connect.

What is the type of connection you want to have ? Objects being not in the same thread , it can not be a direct connection, so it is up to you to choose between Qt::QueuedConnection and Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection

In any case it needs to go through the event loop to ends up in the slot on the modbusThread

I would also assert the result of the connect , it returns a bool that worth checking

Comment: Thx, but I'd tried to connect it in different ways. And I've done it right now (to connect after moving). It didn't help.
It is automatically chosen queued connection and I'd like to have it.
Connection returns bool, I've cheched.
Also, I've fordot to mention, that some other signal-slot connections between theese objects work!

Comment: are you sure your modbusThread is idle at this point ? I see that you have another connection upon thread starting, so maybe the modbusThread is busy  in the process function : 
connect(modbusThread, &QThread::started, modbusH, &modbusHandler::process);

You should check what is the modbusThread doing when you are on the emit breakpoint.

Comment: In that moment my thread is waiting. I use QWaitCondition to control its work. And other slot can be called from this state. But not this.